# a question about the seed of np.random.permutation

Tags: python, numpy, random

I'm trying to shuffle my data along the first axis. The code is as following:

```
shuffle_indexes = np.random.permutation(new_data.shape[0])
new_data = new_data[shuffle_indexes]
```

I wanna set a random seed to the function in order to replicate the result and control variables. But I check the official website and I didn't find such parameters for the function. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
numpy.random.seed(0)
```

Sets the seed.

In your specific case you can also short the code to shuffle the array using

```
numpy.random.shuffle(array)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! If I set the seed that way, does it mean that this seed is passed to all the numpy random function?

Comment: Yes, all the numpy random function calls afterwards will have a deterministic result